# Падеж фразеологизмов и словосочетаний по типу "сам(а) + существительное" в деепричастных оборотах

Tags: согласование, деепричастный-оборот

*Он был сама непосредственность.

Она была ни рыба ни мясо.*

А если использовать эти словосочетания как части деепричастного оборота, какой требуется падеж?
***Будучи сама непосредственность, он...*** или ***Будучи самой непосредственностью, он...***?
***Будучи ни рыба ни мясо, она...*** или ***Будучи ни рыбой ни мясом, она...?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Есть такое понятие, как  нормы фразеологии и фразеологические ошибки. В частности, не допускается  **искажение грамматической формы** компонентов (слов) в составе фразеологизмов.
2. Глагольная форма ***будучи*** управляет Т.п., и есть все основания предполагать, что, к примеру,  фразеологизмы ***ни рыба ни мясо, ни то ни се*** используются в единственной падежной форме, а другие варианты им противопоказаны.

Поэтому весьма рискованно использовать названные словосочетания, а лучше сказать так: Он был человек заурядный (обыкновенный), ни то ни се (ни рыба ни мясо).

3. Можно также считать, что сочетание ***сама непосредственность*** также имеет ограниченные возможности в этом плане.

**САМ**, II. местоим. прил. 3. только ед. **Воплощённый, олицетворённый.** Ты само совершенство. Хозяйка-то сама простота. Его слог – само изящество. Ваш протест – сама правда.

Поэтому выражения "будучи сама непосредственность" или "будучи самой непосредственностью" одинаково некорректны.

Впрочем, вопрос дискуссионный.

Comment: А чем вообще является в предложении типа 'Он был сама простота' словосочетание 'сама простота'? Это определение?

Comment: Я считаю, что именная часть сказуемого, но в форме И. п.

Comment: Хм. Не похоже, разве в составном именном сказуемом ощущается тире? А в подобных конструкциях оно, по моим ощущениям, может быть уместным: "Лес был — сама красота!"

Comment: *В частности, не допускается искажение грамматической формы компонентов* — где-то прописан запрет на склонение?

Comment: @Nektoid При наличии связки тире интонационное.  Если ставите тире, то ударение падает  на подлежащее: ЛЕс был – сама красота. Если не ставите тире, то ударение падает на сказумое: Лес был сама красотА.  Контекст  у вариантов может быть разный, а вот сказуемое во всех случаях составное именное.  Так что всё на усмотрение автора.

Comment: @oleedd  Вы видите, что написано? Вопрос дискуссионный. Это я для вас написала. Вот, думаю, завтра oleedd непременно спросит: а где это прописано? Поэтому это задание для вас: поищите, где. Или вы эти фразеологизмы склонять будете?  Если бы я знала, где найти эту информацию,  то указала бы ее. Да только вам тогда что останется делать?  И много ли в Нацкорпусе примеров, где они склоняются. Где-то от нуля до одного, да и то автору можно указать на ненормативность конструции.

Comment: А я не против склонения. У меня звучит, не вижу в этом плохого, даже разговорным вариантом не сочту. Ну вы ж говорите, что не допускается искажение. Вот и спросил про источник. Пытался что-то найти, не удалось. *да и то автору можно указать на ненормативность конструкции* — ненормативность должна быть где-то прописана.

Comment: Искажение не допускается, но эта тема где-то должна рассматриваться подробно, я же видела только общую рекомендацию и некоторые примеры.  А  то, что на практике именно эти фразеологизмы не склоняюся, вам ни о чем не говорит? Или приведите нам авторитетные классические и современные примеры, где они склоняются, тоже будет неплохо. Вот это и называется дискуссия.

Comment: Да просто боятся склонять. Меня давно волнует вопрос, где можно сделать поиск только по классике? То есть там должна быть собрана вся классика.

Comment: Я так не считаю, я сначала на слух определила, что формы кажутся некорректными.  Возьмите Толстого, Тургенева, Достоевского и проверьте в Нацкорпусе хотя бы их, чем вам не классики.

Comment: А как там задать писателей? Разве можно?

Comment: А там можно задать подкорпус (по времени написания, по автору и т.д.). Попробуйте.

Comment: Ясно. Но всё равно там избранные произведения классиков, а не все. И лучше уже по всему искать. Использование "будучи" притянуто за уши, там да, на слух определяется некорректность. А как в примерах shampar'а?

Comment: Тоже никуда не годится. Выглядит или как грамматическая некорректность, или как современное просторечие.

Comment: А мне норм. А порой у нас наоборот.

Answer (score 0):

Если верить НКРЯ, лишь двое авторов имели смелость по-своему просклонять это сочетание. Выглядит, мягко говоря, неубедительно.

> Я нахожу, что вы слишком много уступили против первоначального
> проекта, и боюсь, чтобы, вследствие этого, учреждение не оказалось ни
> рыбой ни мясом. [В. П. Мещерский. Мои воспоминания (1897)]
>
> Коршунов же Ромку за все это зауважал, хотя до этого считал ни рыбой
> ни мясом. [Галина Щербакова. Подробности мелких чувств (2000)]

Вопрос о трансформации фразеологизма (перестаёт ли он после изменений оставаться таковым) надо обсуждать отдельно.

Comment: Во втором примере по-другому не получится.

Comment: Согласен. Пример из XIX в. более мудрёный.

Comment: Что-то с логикой в вашем предложении. *Если верить НКРЯ, лишь двое авторов имели смелость* — в Нацкорпусе нет всех текстов, там лишь капля в море. Звучит так, будто Нацкорпус позволяет узнать о всех тех, кто имел смелость. И что, интересно, будет, если не верить? И они точно не по-своему склоняли, а по стандарту.

Comment: Читать надо так, как написано: «Если верить НКРЯ, лишь двое ...». Только два примера по теме вопроса.

Comment: По-русски надо писать. Например: *В Нацкорпусе есть лишь два примера...* А у вас: *Если поверить источнику, всего два автора имели смелость...* Дело не в понимании, а в корректности самого предложения.

Comment: Спасибо. Хоть кто-то понимает, как надо писать. Другие и читать-то не знают как.

Comment: Глагол "верить" не подходит.

Comment: Как скажете, так и напишем.

Comment: Сложно исправить это предложение. Там проблема на проблеме.